# Problems with groups in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm quite sure that this has a simple solution, but I've been searching for three hours and haven't managed to find anything that helps me.

I'm writing a parser in Java using regex and I'm supposed to be able to match some previously decided words, numbers from 1-10000 and hex color codes. Now it's going great matching the words, but the reader isn't reading the numbers and color codes as a whole. For example it reads the input:

> DOWN. COLOR #000000.

as:

> Reading: DOWN   Returning: Down
>
> Reading: .   Returning: Dot
>
> Reading:    Returning: Whitespace
>
> Reading: COLOR   Returning: Color
>
> Reading:    Returning: Whitespace
>
> Reading: #   Returning: nothing
>
> Reading: 0   Returning: Number
>
> Reading: A   Returning: nothing
>
> Reading: F   Returning: nothing
>
> Reading: 2   Returning: Number
>
> Reading: 3   Returning: Number
>
> Reading: 4   Returning: Number
>
> Reading: .   Returning: Dot

So it's able to read the words COLOR and DOWN as a whole as I want but it doesn't read the color code #000000. I would ideally want those seven lines to be:

> Reading: #0AF234  Returning: Colorcode

I have:

```
String stringTokens = "DOWN|COLOR|(\\s|\\t)+|\\n|\b[1-9][0-9]{0,3}\b|10000|^(#)([a-fA-F0-9]{6})$";
Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile(stringTokens, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = stringPattern.matcher(input);
```

Then:

```
while (m.find()) {
        if (m.start() != inputPos) {
            tokens.add(new Token(lineNo, TokenType.Invalid));
        }
        if (m.group().matches("^(#)([a-fA-F0-9]{6})$"))
            tokens.add(new Token(lineNo, TokenType.ColorCode));             
        else if (m.group().equals("."))
            tokens.add(new Token(lineNo, TokenType.Dot));
        else if (m.group().matches("DOWN"))
            tokens.add(new Token(lineNo, TokenType.Down));
        else if (m.group().matches("COLOR"))
            tokens.add(new Token(lineNo, TokenType.Color));
        else if (Character.isDigit(m.group().charAt(0)))
            tokens.add(new Token(lineNo, TokenType.Number, Integer.parseInt(m.group())));
        else if (m.group().matches("\\n")) {
            tokens.add(new Token(lineNo, TokenType.Whitespace));
            lineNo++;
        }
        else if (m.group().matches("(\\s|\\t)+"))
            tokens.add(new Token(lineNo, TokenType.Whitespace));
        inputPos = m.end();
    }
```

So my question is basically:

**How do I manage to read the groups regarding the color codes and numbers together?** When I print out m.group() for each reading now, it only returns single digits. Yet I was looking at another code where the digits are read in the same format, with the regex above simply *[0-9]+*, which is too simple for me. Then each group was read as the whole number.

I have tried to use something along the lines of m.group(1) and m.group(2), used the word boundaries (which I don't understand completely) and the ^$ format, but nothing seems to work to read the token as a whole.

I hope I managed to keep the code I copied simple without missing anything important, and that someone can help me figure this simple (it must be?!) thing out. Thank you! :)

Comment: do all lines have a particular format? eg UP/DOWN then COLOR then a hex code? if so, your life would be easier if you parsed the whole line instead of bits of it.  Let me know.

Comment: @Bohemian They have no particular format but a COLOR has to be followed by 1+ spaces, then color code, 0+ spaces and a dot. A syntax error is thrown if this is not the order, and I'm doing that in the parser, but this is just the lexer I'm trying to get to recognize a valid input. I have to work more with the hex code later so I'm not sure what is best to do with it in the lexer.

Now it's recognizing the exact words, like UP and DOWN, but not uP, down, and hex codes. It only validates what EQUALS, but never matches, except for in the case of whitespaces. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a regexp:

```
DOWN|COLOR|(\\s|\\t)+|\\n|\b[1-9][0-9]{0,3}\b|10000|^(#)([a-fA-F0-9]{6})$
```

That we can decompose as:

- `DOWN`
- `COLOR`
- `(\\s|\\t)++`: *one* or more \s (OK, this is a whitespace class) or \t (not really needed as \t is included in \s)
- `\\n` (note this is also included in the \s)
- `\b[1-9][0-9]{0,3}\b`: Ok, here you try to use a word-boundary, but you are not taking into account that backslashes need to escaped in a Java string, so it should be `\\b`. Not sure why would you want to use that?
- `10000`: isn't this covered by the previous pattern?
- `^(#)([a-fA-F0-9]{6})$`: The (#) seems unnecessary, just #. With the ^...$ you're forcing that only content of the input to be the #abcdabcd, so I'd remove it.

How do you match the dot?

Since you need to match again to distinguish the different types of tokens, why don't use multiple regexp (one for each token) (or no regexp at all for the literals) that you will check against the head of the string to parse.

If it matches you have a new token and you can consume the matched part of the string.

Comment: Thank you! It turned out that I was matching the dot in the wrong way. I was doing it but forgot to copy that part to the question, which is a mistake that cost me some time! It threw off the hex code and number matching but everything is working now. I do a \\n separately since I'm keeping a count of the lines. 

I was doing: m.group().equals(".") - and it always read a dot correctly so I didn't give it more thought. Now I do:
m.group().matches("\\."). Something that I should have realized earlier but the error was in another place!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the begin and end-line tokens in the regex around the hex-number part?

e.g. (in Clojure, which just uses the java.util.regex).

With the `^` and `$` in, it can't tokenize the hex color (original regex). It can't recognize the hex.

```
user=> (def r #"DOWN|COLOR|(\\s|\\t)+|\\n|\b[1-9][0-9]{0,3}\b|10000|^(#)([a-fA-F0-9]{6})$")
#'user/r
user=> (re-seq r "DOWN. COLOR #000000.")
(["DOWN" nil nil nil] ["COLOR" nil nil nil])
```

But without the begin/end line tokens, it can.

```
user=> (def r #"DOWN|COLOR|(\\s|\\t)+|\\n|\b[1-9][0-9]{0,3}\b|10000|(#)([a-fA-F0-9]{6})")
#'user/r
user=> (re-seq r "DOWN. COLOR #000000.")
(["DOWN" nil nil nil] ["COLOR" nil nil nil] ["#000000" nil "#" "000000"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to assert that if `COLOR` is present, then the color should be correctly formatted. Also, to make life easier, just convert the line to uppercase before working with it. You can do it without a lot of code and without a `Matcher` if you use `replaceAll()` judiciously:

```
input = input.toUpperCase();
if (input.matches(".*\\bCOLOR\\b.*")) {
    String color = input.replaceAll(".*\\bCOLOR\\b +(?:(#[A-F0-9]{6})\\.)?.*", "$1");
    if (color.isEmpty()) {
         // incorrect syntax
    }
}
```

The `replaceAll()` *optionally* captures the color code, but matches the whole input regardless, so if the input doesn't conform, group 1 captures nothing - returning a blank. If it conforms, you get the color code.